# Analysis of a Circuit Simulation with Fault

Tags: circuit-analysis

I need to simulate this circuit in order to know how much voltage and current will generate the fault at the load.
[image: circuit]

In this circuit I use a fast blow 7A fuse, a P Mosfet IRF5305 with +- 20V Vgs as maximum, a 10 ohm 1w resistor at the gate and a TVS 1N6376 unidirectional tvs diode with 16.5V max clamp at 70A 1500w. The working voltage of the diode is 12v and the breakdown is 14.1V

The fault I want to simulate as you can see is when you put 25v at input, that voltage will exceed max voltage of the Vgs mosfet so it will fail.
The load is a 85W one (imagine a notebook connected as an example).

I dont know what will happen to the circuit next. The fuse will blow?, the tvs will derivate all current to gnd?, how much voltage and current will see the load?

Maybe anyone with experience in circuit simulation can help me. I recently purchase Multisim 14.0 but I am getting experience till today.

Comment: Have you tried putting together a simulation yourself? Do you really want to do the simulation or do you just want someone to give you the answer?

Comment: Thanks Elliot!. 2 hours ago I tried with the software I mention, but putting an osciloscope at the output does not give me good result as my lack of experience in simulation. So what I expect is anyone with experience could answer my question and if can simulate the circuit too I would be so grateful.